# Configure decorators for generic interfaces and inject all instances to constructor with non generic interface argument in Simple Injector

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, decorator, simple-injector

I've been using a pattern very similar to what is described [in this excellent article](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) to have commands and queries as objects. I am also using SimpleInjector as the DI container.

The only significant difference is that rather that controller take an explicit dependency on some `ICommandHandler<TCommand>` I want the controllers to take a dependency on an object (a `Dispatcher`) which will take a `ICommand` instance and resolve the correct handler for that command.  This will reduce the number of parameters that the constructors need to take and make the whole thing a little easier to use.

So my `Dispatcher` objects constructor looks like this:

```
public CommandAndQueryDispatcher(IEnumerable<ICommandHandler> commandHandlers,
    IEnumerable<IQueryHandler> queryHandlers)
{
}
```

and my CommandHandler interfaces look like this:

```
public interface ICommandHandler<in TCommand> : ICommandHandler 
    where TCommand : ICommand
{
    void Execute(TCommand command, ICommandAndQueryDispatcher dispatcher);
}

public interface ICommandHandler
{
    void Execute(object command, ICommandAndQueryDispatcher dispatcher);
}
```

And a typical command handler looks like:

```
public abstract class CommandHandlerBase<TCommand> : ICommandHandler<TCommand> 
    where TCommand : ICommand
{
    public abstract void Execute(TCommand command, ICommandAndQueryDispatcher dispatcher);

    public void Execute(object command, ICommandAndQueryDispatcher dispatcher)
    {
        Execute((TCommand) command, dispatcher);
    }
}

internal class DeleteTeamCommandHandler : CommandHandlerBase<DeleteTeamCommand>
{
    public DeleteTeamCommandHandler(){        }

    public override void Execute(DeleteTeamCommand command, 
        ICommandAndQueryDispatcher dispatcher)
    {
       ... functionality here...
    }
}
```

However this change had some knockons and now I want to add some decorators to my commands and queries I've having some problems.

In order to have all of the commands and queries injected into the `Dispatcher` I made them all have a base, genericless, interface `ICommandHandler` and `IQueryHandler`, then interrogate the instances actually received (which are generic) to get the type of command they handle to register them so I can look up the handler based on the type of the given command later on.

Now when I try and use decorators as indicated in the examples I can't seem to get anything injected into my `Dispatcher`, as the decorated instances are registered as generic types, so don't get resolved as basic `ICommandHandler` instances. If I try making the decorators non generic then the instances which are injected don't have any generic type parameters so I can't find what type of command its a handler for.

I feel like I must be missing something fairly simple.

So my question is either

- How can I get all instances of an open generic type from the container cast as a base interface passed into my `Dispatcher`?

OR

- Is there a better way for me to implement the dispatcher functionality so that my controllers can be ignorant of which handler is going to handle a command/query which plays more nicely with SimpleInjector?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> This will reduce the number of parameters that the constructors need
>   to take and make the whole thing a little easier to use

Please take a close watch on this, because by doing this, you might hide the fact that your controllers do too much; violate the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). SRP violations tend to lead to maintainability issues later on. There's even a [follow up article](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92) of the author of the article you refer to (that's me btw) that states:

> I certainly wouldn’t advocate an ICommandProcessor [that's
>   ICommandAndQueryDispatcher in your case] for executing commands -
>   consumers are less likely to take a dependency on many command
>   handlers and if they do it would probably be a violation of SRP. ([source](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92))

The article even discusses a solution for this for queries, but you can apply it to your commands as well. But you should consider stripping your solution down and remove the non-generic interfaces. You don't need them.

Instead, define the following:

```
public interface ICommandHandler<TCommand> : where TCommand : ICommand
{
    void Execute(TCommand command);
}
```

Do note a few things:

1. There's no non-generic interface.
2. You don't pass through the `ICommandAndQueryDispatcher`. That's just ugly. The `ICommandAndQueryDispatcher` is a service and services need to be passed through constructor injection. The `command` on the other hand is runtime data, and [runtime data is passed through using method arguments](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99). So if there's a command or query handler that needs the dispatcher: inject it through the constructor.
3. There's no `in` keyword for `TCommand`. Since commands are use cases, there *should be* a one-to-one mapping between a command and a command handler implementation. Specifying an 'in' however means that one command class can map to multiple handlers, but this should not be the case. When dealing with events and event handlers on the other hand, this will be a much more obvious approach.
4. No more `CommandHandlerBase<TCommand>`. You don't need that. I would argue that a good design hardly ever needs a base class.

Another thing, don't try to mix the dispatcher for commands with that for the queries. Two responsibilities means two classes. This is how your command dispatcher will look:

```
// This interface is defined in a core application layer
public interface ICommandDispatcher
{
    void Execute(ICommand command);
}

// This class is defined in your Composition Root (where you wire your container)
// It needs a dependency to the container.
sealed class CommandDispatcher : ICommandDispatcher
{
    private readonly Container container;

    public CommandDispatcher(Container container) {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public void Execute(ICommand command) {
        var handlerType = typeof(ICommandHandler<>)
            .MakeGenericType(command.GetType());

        dynamic handler = container.GetInstance(handlerType);

        handler.Handle((dynamic)command);
    }
}
```

Do note that you don't inject a collection of command handlers here, but instead to request a handler from the container. This code will only contain infrastructure and no business logic, so if you place this implementation close to the code that is responsible of wiring the container, you will [not](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/08/25/ServiceLocatorrolesvs.mechanics/) abuse the [Service Locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/), and this is a valid approach. The rest of the application in that case still doesn't depend on the DI framework.

You can register this `CommandDispatcher` as follows:

```
container.RegisterSingle<ICommandDispatcher>(new CommandDispatcher(container));
```

If you take this approach, because you request a handler by the `ICommandHandler<TCommand>` interface, the container will automatically wrap the handlers with any decorators that must be applied according to your configuration and the generic type constraints you applied.

Comment: Thanks Steven. splitting the command dispatcher and the query dispatcher is on the list of things to do. The dispatcher is passed through the execute method so that the commands can use it to execute queries to get the data they need whilst processing the command. This is what triggered the decision to split the dispatcher interface as it doesn't make sense to allow commands to execute other commands I don't think, but queries seem Ok.

Comment: @SamHolder: Please keep in mind the simple rule: "pass runtime data through method invocations; pass in [design time] services through constructor injection."

Comment: Yeah I don't know why asking for the dispatcher through the constructor of the handler didn't occur to me. Sometimes you just need to step back from things a little bit. Thanks for the great (and quick! ) feedback.

Comment: Hi, I am trying a sample using simpleinjector and I have written the the generic command, command handler and a commanddecorator as instructed. But I don't know how to get the right handler for a given command at runtime . any help on that would be great.thanks.

Comment: @Steven I was looking for this - dynamic handler = container.GetInstance(handlerType); - this is how one can get the right handler. Thanks.

Comment: @Aravind: Usually you only need dispatching with commands when sending them over the wire. For other cases I suggest simply injecting a specific command handler interface through a constructor.

Comment: @Steven in my case the commands are inserted in a queue and a service picks them up and processes. While processing each command , the service need to call the appropriate handler and I was thinking of how to do it.

Comment: @Aravind: Yep. That's a valid reason for dispatching.

Comment: @Steven I have added it as a separate question with code and tagged simple injector.

Comment: This is a great answer, I have exactly this architecture in my app and it helped me hugely. One question, **"Do note that you don't inject a collection of command handlers here, but instead to request a handler from the container. This code will only contain infrastructure and no business logic, so if you place this implementation close to the code that is responsible of wiring the container"** I was trying to do this at first, writing a CommandDespatcher on the same pattern as your CompositeValidator, but I could not get SI to inject an IEnumerable<ICommandHandler<ICommand>>. Is it possible?

Comment: @PhilipDaniels: Yes, it is absolutely possible to let Simple Injector inject an enumerable, but you shouldn't do that, because you would have iterate -and create- all those command handlers (possibly hundreds) to find the single one you wish to execute, which an O(n) operation, while the `CommandDispatcher` as shown in my answer is an O(1) operation. So my advice is to use the described `CommandDispatcher`, or as I describe in my answer, prefer not to use it at all, but inject ICommandHandler<T> directly into consumers.